MySql in Kuberentes cluster wont allow connections even from inside the container
Kubernetes beginner here.
I've stumbled upon a weird problem.
I just started using kubernetes and have succesfully created a cluster with a master and worker node.
(i have already gotten a nginx webserver working with a custom html file on the cluster)
After that i tried getting a test database to work.
I've tried connecting to the mysql database created with the config files underneath but i keep getting the error error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' when using "mysql -u root -p" with the password "password"
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: db-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  sql-root-password: cGFzc3dvcmQ=  # This is base64 for "password"
  sql-root-user: cm9vdA==          # This is base64 for "root"
  sql-test-password: cGFzc3dvcmQ=  # This is base64 for "password"
  sql-test-user: dGVzdHVzZXI=      # This is base64 for "testuser"

I've also tried deleting and recerating the persistent storage underneath in case it was possible unwated files kept keeping it from working:
kubectl  delete deployment mysql-deployment
kubectl delete pvc mysql-pv-claim
kubectl delete pv mysql-pv-volume
sudo rm -rf /mnt/data

Persistentstorage:
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi

And the service and deployment:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mysql
          image: mysql
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
          env:
          - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            valueFrom: 
              secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-secret
                  key: sql-root-password
          - name: MYSQL_USER
            valueFrom: 
              secretKeyRef:
                name: db-secret
                key: sql-test-user
          - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
            valueFrom: 
              secretKeyRef:
                name: db-secret
                key: sql-test-password   
          - name: MYSQL_DATABASE            
            value: "test"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysql-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: db-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3306        # Port inside the cluster
      targetPort: 3306  # Container's port
      nodePort: 30036   # Port accessible from outside (adjust the port as needed)
  type: NodePort        # Exposes the service via NodePort


logs of the pod after starting:
k logs pod/mysql-deployment-6c89db4c66-w79mf
2024-09-19 12:54:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 9.0.1-1.el9 started.
2024-09-19 12:54:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2024-09-19 12:54:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 9.0.1-1.el9 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2024-09-19T12:54:03.149759Z 0 [System] [MY-015015] [Server] MySQL Server - start.
2024-09-19T12:54:03.469981Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 9.0.1) starting as process 1
2024-09-19T12:54:03.484521Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-09-19T12:54:04.147597Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-09-19T12:54:04.539580Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2024-09-19T12:54:04.539662Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2024-09-19T12:54:04.545997Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2024-09-19T12:54:04.609784Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2024-09-19T12:54:04.610074Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '9.0.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

And the get all command
k get all
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/mysql-deployment-6c89db4c66-w79mf   1/1     Running   0          14m
pod/web-deployment-7749f585d8-4zs2n     1/1     Running   0          163m
pod/web-deployment-7749f585d8-5mjqs     1/1     Running   0          163m
pod/web-deployment-7749f585d8-q24rb     1/1     Running   0          163m

NAME                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/db-service    NodePort    10.100.87.70   <none>        3306:30036/TCP   150m
service/kubernetes    ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          2d
service/web-service   NodePort    10.98.7.161    <none>        443:30080/TCP    176m

NAME                               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/mysql-deployment   1/1     1            1           14m
deployment.apps/web-deployment     3/3     3            3           163m

NAME                                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/mysql-deployment-6c89db4c66   1         1         1       14m
replicaset.apps/web-deployment-7749f585d8     3         3         3       163m

I've tried the following:
After not being able to connect with mysqlworkbench i tried connecting via the terminal inside the container:
bash-5.1# mysql -u testuser -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'testuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
and i also triend without setting the root password so it would be empty but without succes.
I've found that sometimes a newline char can end up in the secret which i made sure i don't have:
kubectl describe secret db-secret
Name:         db-secret
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
sql-root-password:  8 bytes
sql-test-password:  8 bytes
sql-test-user:      8 bytes

I also checked if the env keys where being set correctly:
k exec -it mysql-deployment-cb7df7f7f-kbhqz -- /bin/bash
bash-5.1# printenv MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
password

All help is appreciated!

If your error is "access denied", then the network wiring and what not is correct.  Did data already exist in the PersistentVolume before you set or changed sql-root-password?  The standard database images will only set credentials on first startup.  (Consider using a StatefulSet rather than manually creating a PersistentVolumeClaim, and definitely avoid hostPath: volumes, which can misplace data in real environments.)

The password has not changed since i started with the db. But after your comment regarding the volumes i deleted the volume completly from the deployment itself and now i can login. So it must have been some leftover files that caused the problem. I'il definetly look into statfulsets next, thanks for the pointers!
